# SQLite SELECT with max() performance

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have a table with about 1.5 million rows and three columns. Column 'timestamp' is of type REAL and indexed. I am accessing the SQLite database via PHP PDO.

The following three selects run in less than a millisecond:

```
select timestamp from trades
select timestamp + 1 from trades
select max(timestamp) from trades
```

The following select needs almost half a second:

```
select max(timestamp) + 1 from trades
```

Why is that?

EDIT:
Lasse has asked for a "explain query plan", I have run this within a PHP PDO query since I have no direct SQLite3 command line tool access at the moment. I guess it does not matter, here is the result:

```
explain query plan select max(timestamp) + 1 from trades:
    [selectid] => 0
    [order] => 0
    [from] => 0
    [detail] => SCAN TABLE trades (~1000000 rows)

explain query plan select max(timestamp) from trades:
    [selectid] => 0
    [order] => 0
    [from] => 0
    [detail] => SEARCH TABLE trades USING COVERING INDEX tradesTimestampIdx (~1 rows)
```

Comment: Try executing this statement from the SQLite3 command line tool: `explain query plan select max(timestamp)+1 from trades;` and tell us what it says, then do the same for `explain query plan select max(timestamp) from trades;`

Comment: Because PHP uses an outdated SQLite version, which cannot properly optimize the last query.

Comment: @CL. Can you provide a reference for this, which might agree with my explanation given below?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the latest SQLite version, the two last queries are fast. In any SQLite version, the first two queries are fast only if you don't read all results.

Comment: I have added the outcome of the `explain query plan`. I guess Tim's answer is correct? Is there a workaround within SQL? I can of course add one in PHP after running the query, but the select is currently a sub query and I prefer to leave it like that. Ok I might test this with the current version of SQLite.

Comment: Your SQLite does not appear to be using an index on the slow query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this query

```
select max(timestamp) + 1 from trades
```

takes so long is that the query engine must, for *each* record, compute the `MAX` value and then add one to it.  Computing the `MAX` value involves doing a full table scan, and this must be repeated for each record because you are adding one to the value.

In the query

```
select timestamp + 1 from trades
```

you *are* doing a calculation for each record, but the engine only needs to scan the entire table once.  And in this query

```
select max(timestamp) from trades
```

the engine *does* have to scan the entire table, however it also does so only once.

From the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html):

> Queries that contain a single MIN() or MAX() aggregate function whose argument is the left-most column of an index *might* be satisfied by doing a single index lookup rather than by scanning the entire table.

I emphasized *might* from the documentation, because it appears that a full table scan may be necessary for a query of the form `SELECT MAX(x)+1 FROM table`
if column `x` be not the left-most column of an index.

Comment: Why does it have to calculate the max+1 for each row, it still only returns 1 resulting value?

Comment: If the query is not being optimized, this is the "default" way it would be executed.

Comment: So this is basically a limitation of the query optimizer? I don't see how this works, max(timestamp)+1 returns the same value for each rows, and then all but one is thrown away and 1 result row is returned, why does it do that?

Comment: No, I don't have an explanation of the observations, I just don't understand why the query engine of SQLite would calculate one value for each row and throw everything away, max(timestamp) is an aggregated value and it should be able to answer that with one index seek or worst case one table scan, then only afterwards add 1 to it. I don't understand why it would execute this for each row. Where is this documented?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Let's see what the query plan is for his SQLite queries.  Maybe there is something else going on which he didn't state in his original problem.  In any case, I'm prepared to remove this answer when a better explanation comes to the surface.